# What are the parameter of statsmodels.api.tsa.get_forcast?

Tags: python, python-3.x, statsmodels

I want to use Python's statsmodels.api.tsa.get_forcast to forcast the data out of the sample,this is my code:

```
mod=sm.tsa.SARIMAX(hs300['Close'],order=(2,1,2),seasonal_order=(2,1,2,12),enforce_stationarity=False,enforce_invertibility=False)
result=mod.fit()
pred=result.get_forcast(20)
```

I want to get the next 20 days data which is out of my sample, this is my mistake:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

How could I solve this problem? I find the document of this function, but this file did not give me enough information of this function:

```
get_forecast(steps=1, **kwargs) method of statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax.SARIMAXResults instance
Out-of-sample forecasts

Parameters
----------
steps : int, str, or datetime, optional
    If an integer, the number of steps to forecast from the end of the
    sample. Can also be a date string to parse or a datetime type.
    However, if the dates index does not have a fixed frequency, steps
    must be an integer. Default
**kwargs
    Additional arguments may required for forecasting beyond the end
    of the sample. See `FilterResults.predict` for more details.
```

There is not a example for the function,who can give an instance for this function?

Comment: show the full traceback, or at least the last part that shows the location where it raises the exception.

Comment: any news about this?

Comment: What do you get when you do `result.summary()`? Do you know if you have a good model?

Answer (score 1):

Please, try "result.predicted_mean". This works for me.
If you do "print(type(result))", you might get more information regarding PredictionResults object.
I hope this would help.

Comment: It should be "print(dir(result))" , not print(type(result)). Sorry for inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use .get_forecast() then you would have to say .get_forecast(steps=). The steps= can be a datetime string or an integer
Use this link for more reference --> https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax.SARIMAXResults.get_forecast.html#statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax.SARIMAXResults.get_forecast